# Scrape Key Check Failed Please Try Again - What is this Error?

Tags: writing

I am encountering an error on my website [ https://cursivecapital.com ] that says "[Scrape Key Check Failed]" whenever I try to update changes in the Theme file.

I'm unable to identify the reason and cause behind this issue. I have already sought assistance from the hosting support, but they were unable to resolve it and suggested contacting the developer.
Given this situation, what steps can I take to address and fix the problem? I would appreciate any guidance or solutions you can provide.

[image: Issue for Scrape Key Check Failed Please Try Again]

Comment: This looks like a programming question, so it would be off topic here.  Ty posting on stackoverflow.com